# How to make a workeable <a href.. in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this code

```
$patterns = "!((http:/{2}[\w\.]{2,}[/\w\-\.\?\&\=\#]*)|(www\.[/\w\-\.\?\&\=\#]*)|([a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+(com|us|co.il)[^\s]*))!e";
 return preg_replace($patterns, "'<a class=\"highlight boughtAt\" href=\"\\1\" title=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\">'.(strlen('\\1')>=$chr_limit ? substr('\\1',0,$chr_limit).'$add':'\\1').'</a>'", $url);
```

But my problem is that if I get the `www.` or just `.com` I get in the href= the prefix of the domain that I'm in.
How can i avoid it? Just get a working link?

Thanks in advance,
Roy

Comment: Please describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Please provide a list of 3 possible inputs, and the values you expect to extract. e.g. `http://www.something.com/ => www.something.com`

Comment: `/{2}` – Why so complicated? Why not just `//`?

Comment: The sentence under the code sample is quite a mess, could you rephrase it a bit, please!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a lookbehind assertion - `(?<=...)` then always add in the http:// in your link:

```
$patterns = "!(((?<=http:/{2})[\w\.]{2,}[/\w\-\.\?\&\=\#]*)|(www\.[/\w\-\.\?\&\=\#]*)|([a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+(com|us|co.il)[^\s]*))!e";
return preg_replace($patterns, "'<a class=\"highlight boughtAt\" href=\"http://\\1\" title=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\">'.(strlen('\\1')>=$chr_limit ? substr('\\1',0,$chr_limit).'$add':'\\1').'</a>'", $url);
```